# Do I need to know any specific computer language or framework to use ROS?

Tags: python, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do I have to know both C++ *and* Python to use ROS?

Do I need to learn any specific frameworks?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9079/do-i-need-to-know-any-specific-computer-language-or-framework-to-use-ros?/) by [Alex Bravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27/alex-bravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 901 on 2011-02-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No.

You can do useful work without knowing either. Both are helpful, but we have successfully introduced ROS to (bright) university freshmen with no previous knowledge of either language.

ROS **is** the framework. You do need to learn that. But, the [introductory tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) are quite good.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6